# Building C with automake under OS X and Linux

Tags: c, linux, macos, github, autotools

Currently I'm writing a RPC system for delay tolerant networks based on the Serval project from Australia [(GitHub)](https://github.com/servalproject/serval-dna) in C.

Mainly I'm developing on macOS El Capitan and everything works fine. But it is somewhat important that my code runs on macOS and Linux. But Linux makes trouble.

I choose automake as my build system since this is the only one I have at least a little experience. I also tried CMake, but with little success.

My problem is now that everything works nice on macOS. But on Linux (Debian) nothing compiles. `autoreconf` produces a configure script without errors, `configure` produces a Makefile without errors. But `make` yields a lot errors. And if I say a lot I really mean a lot (about 75.000 lines).

The first issue is the following:

`In file included
    from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h:29:0,
    from /usr/local/include/curl/curlbuild.h:131,
    from /usr/local/include/curl/curl.h:34,
    from rpc.h:1,
    from main.c:1:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/types.h:30:1: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘typedef’
 typedef unsigned char __u_char;`

I googled around and found some people saying that this type of error comes somewhere from the user code, maybe a missing `;` or similar. But I double-checked everything. And a missing `;` would also be a problem on macOS, too.

My code can be found in my [Github repo.](https://github.com/adur1990/ServalRPC.git) Please use the `dev` branch.
At this point the repo is somewhat disgusting and not clean at all. I will clean up when everything is running.

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of `serval/general/features.h`. Here how it goes:

`curl/curl.h` gets to include `curlbuild.h`, which includes `sys/types.h`.

`sys/types.h` includes `features.h` (expecting the one coming from glibc), which includes `sys/cdefs.h`, which define `__BEGIN_CDECL` (to nothing, since this is C, not C++.)

`sys/types.h` starts with (snipping around the stuff that is not required)

```
__BEGIN_CDECL

typedef unsigned char __u_char;
```

since `__BEGIN_CDECL` is not defined, it errors out.

Avoid using `-Iserval/general` in your command line and include the file with the full relative path, and it should be alright.